# How to increment a column value when creates a table

Tags: mysql, create-table

I create a table which has a column with date (which is complited with user input). Is it possible to add column which is autocomplited by the date inputed + 30 days? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use trigger to achieve this

Comment: try like this `CREATE TRIGGER add_30_day BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW SET  NEW.date = date_add(date,interval 30 day); `

Answer (score 2):

There's no possibility with column settings but you can use a trigger for that:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER interval_bi BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.mydate
        THEN 
            SET NEW.date_and_30 = DATE_ADD(NEW.mydate, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
        END IF;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Same for `BEFORE UPDATE`.

Comment: There is a problem with "END IF;"

Comment: There was an semicolon missing at the end of the `SET` line. I corrected this in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a column with a before insert trigger.

But, why bother?  You could also create a view that has this information:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, (inputdate + interval 1 month) as OneMonthLater
    from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Triggers to achieve this. [See this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)